# file .egg doesn't exist

Tags: python, panda3d

I am trying execute a python script which uses PANDA3D library.

I have this error :
`ERROR: the path '\c\virtual-vision-simulator_master\media\scenes\office_floor\skybox.egg' doesn't exist'`

I have checked and the file exist in this path.

Comment: I think you're not writing the path to the '.egg' file correctly. Can you please show us the code you write (or the relevant parts only if it's too big) and mention which operating system you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Using '\' usually mean an escape char, for example '\n' mean next line.
Try to replace the '\' values by '/'.

```
'/c/virtual-vision-simulator_master/media/scenes/office_floor/skybox.egg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Panda3D uses UNIX-style paths, even on Windows.  This means that you have to use forward slashes instead of backslashes.  So, you should use the following path instead:

```
/c/virtual-vision-simulator_master/media/scenes/office_floor/skybox.egg
```

On top of that, backslashes have a special interpretation in Python (as in many other languages), and if you do have to use backslashes in a string, you have to either put `r` in front of the string (as in `r"a\b"`) or you have to use double backslashes (as in `"a\\b"`).